# SSRS Hide Columns After Last Column with Data

Tags: reporting-services, hide

I have an SSRS report and I would like to be able to hide all the columns that come after the last column with data.

For example, columns are the months of the year, January through December.
For each month I have a value, some months have zero. I only want to display up to the last month that has a value, and hide all columns after that.

If the report looks like this:

```
jan feb march april may june july august september october november december
1    0    1     0    0   0    0     0        1        0       0        0
```

I only want to display January to September

Thanks

Comment: What does your data look like? I don't mean when it is displayed in your report, I mean what does the raw data in the database look like in terms of structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression for hiding the column group when it meets the requirements

```
= Iif(SUM(Fields!value.Value)=0 AND RunningValue(Fields!value.Value, Sum,"Tablix1") = SUM(Fields!value.Value, "Dataset1"),True,False)
```

Change the field and dataset names to match your tablix

[image]

[image]